# Will Java 8 have lazy evaluation?

Tags: java, lazy-evaluation, yield-return

I was working in C# for a long time, and I liked one construct very much, I am talking about **yield return** here. This allowed to organize even infinite collections thanks to lazy evaluation:

```
IEnumerable<int> fib() {
  int a = 0, b= 1;
  while (true) {
    yield return b;
    int c = a;
    a = b;
    b = c+b;
  }
}
```

Will Java 8 have a semantics similar to this? Will it allow the lazy evaluation at it's full power?

Comment: You could also implement `java.util.Enumeration` to achieve the same (without having to add syntactic sugar).

Comment: There is no such thing as yield keyword in Java 8, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess Yes. Check this one out 
http://java.dzone.com/articles/lazy-sequences-implementation

Answer (score 4):

You can write an Iterable like this:

```
class Fibonacci implements Iterable<Integer> {
  public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
    return new Iterator<Integer>() {
      private int a = 0, b = 1;

      public boolean hasNext() {
        return true; // also possible to provide a set limit here
      }

      public Integer next() {
        final int lastA = a;
        a = b;
        b = lastA + b;
        return a;
      }

      public void remove() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
      }
    };
  }
}
```

Then you can iterate over the values like this:

```
for (final Integer i : new Fibonacci()) {
  System.out.print(i + ", ");
  if (i > 100) {
    break;
  }
}
```

So there is no need to wait for Java 8.

Comment: Yes, that's a possibility. However, it takes much more code, than in C#. That's my point. Because any functional feature can be implemented in Java, it's just the question of code amount.

Comment: If you create a `NumericStream` base class, all you need to do is to implement `next()` properly. Then it would be even less code than the C# Variant. A single keyword does not define a Language.